# Перенаправление cо страницы блога на страницу категории?

Tags: wordpress

Привет есть страница категории где выводится названия категории, посты этой категории и линки на другие категории. Тип site.ru/blog/category_one
Однако есть же страница site.ru/blog где вывод всех постой независимо от категории. Можно ли как то данную страницу удалить либо сделать редирект на первую категорию? И как лучше для SEO?

Comment: Можно же прописать редирект в шаблоне этой страницы, например.

Comment: @Сережка, давай ты свои недо-консультации будешь в  другом месте продавать

Comment: Не назначать её для вывод "блога" (если я правильно всё понял)